# php mysql PDO get Fatal error when calling 2 functions to run sql statement in the same file

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 functions in class item->  `display_item()` and `get_category_item()`

```
class db{

protected $db_host;
protected $db_name;
protected $db_user_name;
protected $db_pass;
protected $conn;

public function __construct() {

    $this->db_host="localhost";
    $this->db_name="bs";
    $this->db_user_name="root";
    $this->db_pass="";

    try {   

        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user_name, $this->db_pass);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    }   

    catch(PDOException $e)

        {

        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();

        }
    }
}

require "../../includes/db.php";

class item extends db{

public function display_item($uid){

    $this->user_uid=$uid;

    try{

        $sql="SELECT * FROM item where uid='$this->user_uid'";
        $statement=$this->conn->query($sql);

        while($row=$statement->fetch()){

            $this->display_item[$row['iid']]=[$row['item_id'],$row['item_name'],$row['item_price'],$row['item_quantity']];

        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        ...
    }
}

public function get_category_item($uid,$iid){

        $this->user_uid=$uid;
        $this->item_iid=$iid;

        try{

        $sql="

            SELECT category_item.iid,category_item.uid,item_category.item_category_name,item_category.cid
            FROM category_item
            JOIN item_category
            ON item_category.uid=category_item.uid and item_category.cid=category_item.cid
            where item_category.uid='$this->user_uid' and category_item.iid='$this->item_iid';

        ";

            $statement=$this->conn->query($sql);

            while($row=$statement->fetch()){

                $this->get_category_item_name[]=$row['item_category_name'];

            }

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){     
               ...
        }   
}
}
```

when I call them one by one, it works fine for both functions. However, if I call them both at the same file, I got

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null

```
$display=new item();
$display->display_item(1);
$display->get_category_item(1,383);
```

In other words, I can only call either one of them but not both at the same file. May i know which part went wrong?

Comment: do you have a private $conn with a __construct on your code ?

Comment: @MaximeK it protected. However, if i change to public, i get the same error. So that means it has nothing to do with that?

Comment: can we have the full code ?

Comment: @MaximeK i have add in the db class as well. plz have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is : you dont use the `class db` to make all the database call.

You define `protected $conn;` in the `class db` but use it in the `class item`.

You need to make a `public function makeQuery` in `class db`, its better than creating a constructor in the `class item` (all database query will be executed by the `class db`).

OR you can do `class item extends db` to use `$this->conn->query($sql);`

Comment: yes, i did extends db.  For what you have mentioned, any example for the coding?

Comment: if its extended from db and used `require_once` instead of `require`, normaly this will work. So the problem is somewhere else on your code

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the parameter `conn` anywhere in your class.

This is why you get that error.

I would suggest to make a second class which works with the db and handle it there, or in the `__construct` of the `item` class to set the `conn` parameter.

Comment: I have added in the database connection code, can you show me an example as I am new to oop?