# php constructor is not working correctly with error query() on null

Tags: php, mysql

As you can see from item.php, I have 2 functions to display some items

**display_item_1() and display_item_2()**

When I run the program by calling

```
$item = new item();
$item->display_item_1(1);
$item->display_item_2(1);
```

**It only displays function->display_item_1()**

**but for display_item_2() receives Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null**

In other words, both function display_item_1() and display_item_2() are same coding but just display the 1st one. 
So that means the **constructor in item.php is not correct?**

OR which part did i do wrong?

**db.php**

```
class db{

protected $db_host;
protected $db_name;
protected $db_user_name;
protected $db_pass;

public function __construct() {
$this->db_host="localhost";
$this->db_name="bs";
$this->db_user_name="root";
$this->db_pass="";
}

public function conn(){

try {   
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user_name="root", $this->db_pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $conn;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

**item.php**

```
require "db.php";

class item {

public $user_uid;
protected $item_name;
public $conn;

public function __construct(){
    $db = new db();
    $this->conn= $db->conn();

}

public function display_item_1($uid){

    $this->user_uid=$uid;

    try{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM item where uid='$this->user_uid'";
        $statement=$this->conn->query($sql);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        ... 
    }

}

public function display_item_2($uid){

    $this->user_uid=$uid;

    try{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM item where uid='$this->user_uid'";
        $statement=$this->conn->query($sql);
        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        ...
    }

}
}
```

Comment: `So that means the constructor in item.php is not correct?` Not at all, otherwise the first display item call wouldn't work either.... is there anything that might be unsetting or changing $this->conn anywhere in your methods?

Comment: @Mark What I have posted in the question is all the coding in 2 files without extra coding from elsewhere. Any idea wads wrong?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Edit your first question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mysql PDO get Fatal error when calling 2 functions to run sql statement in the same file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246196/php-mysql-pdo-get-fatal-error-when-calling-2-functions-to-run-sql-statement-in-t)

Comment: @VasilShaddix well, its not really the same question. The previous question i asked hint me the direction to constructor and thats why I changed my coding. 2 questions coding are not really the same. please check

Comment: You don't have `display_item` or `display_item2` methods. You have `display_item_1` and `display_item_2` *respectively*. SoOOOooooo.... `$item->display_item_1(1); 
$item->display_item_2(1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, typo. I already updated it.  in my program its display_item_1 and display_item_2

Comment: @Fred-ii- do you have any idea whats wrong with my coding? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has also been mentioned in your other question and I'll mention it again in this one: rewrite your code and let the DB class handle the querying. Right now your DB class doesn't make sense in terms of object-oriented design, it's not well written and should be rewritten from scratch. Here's just an idea how it could look like:

**db.php**

```
// Use uppercase for class names and stick to possibly unreserved names
class DatabaseHandler
{

    // moved from constructor and set to private, you are surely not using inheritance
    private $db_host="localhost";
    private $db_name="bs";
    private $db_user_name="root";
    private $db_pass="";
    private $connection= FALSE; // added, holds db connection

    /* obsolete in your case 
    public function __construct() { }
    */

    public function connect() 
    {

        try {   
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user_name="root", $this->db_pass);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->connection= $conn;
            return TRUE;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
    * return records from your database; checks skipped in this example
    */
    public function query($query) 
    {
        // only query if a database connection is available, else return false
        if (!$this->connection) return FALSE;
        try {
            $statement=$this->connection->query($query);
            return $statement->fetchAll();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            // logging or whatever ...
            return FALSE;           
        }
    }
}
```

**item.php**

```
class Item {

    public $user_uid;
    private $item_name;
    private $conn; // why make it public?

    public function __construct(){
        $db = new DatabaseHandler();
        if (!$db->connect()) die("Database not available"); // update these lines
        $this->conn= $db; 
    }

    public function display_item_1($uid){
        $this->user_uid=$uid;

        $arrValues= $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM item where uid='$this->user_uid'");
        print_r($arrValues);
    }

    public function display_item_2($uid){
        $this->user_uid=$uid;

        $arrValues= $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM item where uid='$this->user_uid'");
        print_r($arrValues);
    }
}
```

**Run code:**

```
$item = new Item();
$item->display_item_1(1);
$item->display_item_2(1);
```

And please go through some tutorials, especially classes and OOP (object-oriented programming).

Comment: Thx for ur advice. However, I got this error when running your codes. Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on boolean (item.php )on line 18

Comment: Is line 18 located in `display_item_1` or `display_item_2` in your local version of the Item class?

Comment: line 18 refers to this line in item.php  -> $arrValues= $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM item where uid='$this->user_uid'");

Comment: its display_item_1 *

Comment: Made a mistake in my code, instead of return the internal database connection to the `$conn` variable, the instance of the class had to be assigned to the variable. Please update the `__construct` part of Item class and try again.

Comment: imo, there only needs to be one db connection (`DatabaseHandler`). I would store the connection in a static variable and use it when it is set. _More important:_  It should use prepared queries with placeholders.  The query function should accept a query string with with parameterized  placeholders and an associated array of parameters (`$params`). The code 1) prepares the query. 2) executes it with parameters i.e. `$stmt->execute($params);`. Then continues as you have. Why? It is efficient as only one connection is used. It is completely safe from SQL Injection.

Comment: @RyanVincent there are tons of ways to handle database actions, your suggestion would also be useful. The above is just a roughly modified version of the original where the database class deserves the name and handles database actions rather than just returning a connection. In the example above, there is no real need to check for SQL injection (if `user_uid` has been properly escaped) as the statements are hardcoded and not influenced by passed parameters.